# I get an error when I use grepl with paste. Invalid regular expression

Tags: r, paste

i am using the following code to match elements of two column,

```
test = articles[apply(articles, 1, function(i) any(grepl(paste(dictionary, collapse = "|"), i))),]
```

and facing the following error:

```
Error in grepl(paste(dictionary, collapse = "|"), i) : 
  invalid regular expression '3 M SYNDROME|3-M SYNDROME|3-M SYNDROME 1|3M SYNDROME|DOLICHOSPONDYLIC DYSPLASIA|GLOOMY FACE SYNDROME|LE MERRER SYNDROME|THREE M SYNDROME|YAKUT SHORT STATURE SYNDROME|ABDOMINAL AORTIC ANEURYSM|ANEURYSM ABDOMINAL AORTIC|AORTIC ANEURYSM ABDOMINAL|AORTIC ANEURYSM FAMILIAL ABDOMINAL 1|ABSENCE EPILEPSY|ABSENCE SEIZURE|CHILDHOOD ABSENCE EPILEPSY|JUVENILE ABSENCE EPILEPSY|PETIT MAL SEIZURE|PYKNOLEPSY|ACANTHAMOEBA INFECTION|
```

dictionary consists of disease names and synonyms,:

```
   [1] "3 M SYNDROME"                                                                
   [2] "3-M SYNDROME"                                                                
   [3] "3-M SYNDROME 1"                                                              
   [4] "3M SYNDROME"                                                                 
   [5] "DOLICHOSPONDYLIC DYSPLASIA"                                                  
   [6] "GLOOMY FACE SYNDROME"                                                        
   [7] "LE MERRER SYNDROME"                                                          
   [8] "THREE M SYNDROME"                                                            
   [9] "YAKUT SHORT STATURE SYNDROME"                                                
  [10] "ABDOMINAL AORTIC ANEURYSM"                                                   
  [11] "ANEURYSM ABDOMINAL AORTIC"                                                   
  [12] "AORTIC ANEURYSM ABDOMINAL"                                                   
  [13] "AORTIC ANEURYSM FAMILIAL ABDOMINAL 1"                                        
  [14] "ABSENCE EPILEPSY"                                                            
  [15] "ABSENCE SEIZURE"                                                             
  [16] "CHILDHOOD ABSENCE EPILEPSY"                                                  
  [17] "JUVENILE ABSENCE EPILEPSY"                                                   
  [18] "PETIT MAL SEIZURE"                                                           
  [19] "PYKNOLEPSY"                                                                  
  [20] "ACANTHAMOEBA INFECTION"                                                      
  [21] "ACANTHAMOEBA INFECTIONS"                                                     
  [22] "ACANTHAMOEBA KERATITIS"                                                      
  [23] "ACCOMMODATIVE SPASM"
```

Here article is a data frame which consists of various articles.
Dictionary is the list of phrases which I want to match.
Please help me where the error lies?

Comment: Can you please add the contents of `dictionary` to the question?

Comment: Ok, try adding `regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}` and then `grepl(paste(regex.escape(dictionary), collapse = "|"), i, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I have added sample data to the question, I have approximately 17000 enteries in it.

Comment: It gives ```invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'
 ``` error

Comment: Ok, so the approach cannot be used, the regex generated from 17K entries is too big for the regex engines.

Comment: is there any other way through which I can do the same thing?

Comment: can str_detect be used in place of grepl?

Comment: It sounds like you want to find articles with any of 17,000 possible terms/synonyms. That is extremely broad. Maybe you can reduce the number of search terms? Another option would be to create search term groups that you can iterate over.

Comment: Since this is an issue with the maximum allowed regex pattern length `str_detect` will not fix it. Maybe you can group your search terms using cosine distance, and then use these term patterns to get articles with matches. IMO this would be the better approach because you would know which terms were found in which articles.

Comment: @gersht:  `str_detect` doesn't require the giant regexp, because it is vectorized over the `pattern` argument.  See my answer below to see how to make use of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use `%in%` rather than `grepl`, i.e.

```
test = articles[apply(articles, 1, function(i) any(i %in% dictionary)),]
```

This checks for exact matches between your dictionary and the entries in `articles`.  If you were looking for substring matches you should use the `str_detect` function from the `stringr` package, marking the dictionary entries as `fixed` so they aren't misinterpreted as regular expressions:

```
test = articles[apply(articles, 1, function(i) any(stringr::str_detect(i, fixed(dictionary)))),]
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you should mark the answer as "accepted", so that future readers will know it worked without reading through everything.

Comment: how can I get a column which gives the keyword to which the column matches?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it as a separate question.